# Check if a selector have a certain set of classes

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements

I'm trying to be able to check if a selector have a certain sets of classes.

.hasClass() can only check if the selector has one class. And the .is() selector can look for multiple classes but will return true if the selector have at least one of the classes.

But I wan't to achieve a way to check if a selector have both of the classes, and only if it has both of the classes do action.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple list the class names:

```
.foo.bar.bar
```

This selector matches any element that has all the classes *foo*, *bar*, and *baz*.

Comment: How does that relate to the use case he listed? E.g., wanting to query an instance/list via `hasClass`, `is`, etc.? (It would apply if he were trying to *get* a list...) Or can you pass that into `hasClass` or something?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: `.is(".foo.bar.bar")`

Answer (score 2):

The is() function should work for you.

- If you have an element and you write
  is(".foo") then it will return true
  if foo is present.
- if you write is(".foo.bar") then it
  will return true if foo AND bar is
  present.
- If you write is(".foo,.bar") then it
  will return true if foo OR bar is
  present.

Answer (score 2):

I think `$.is('.class1.class2')` will do what you want. For example, `$('#foo').is('.a.b')` returns true for the following `div`, but `$('#foo').is('.a.c')` will return false:

```
<div id="foo" class="a b"></div>
```

Isn't that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

does `$('div.class1.class2')` not do what you're after (ie, find any div with class1 and class2)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It completely eliminates the use for hasClass & is. The OP can just use the correct selector in the first place rather than eg/ get all div then check for class1 & class2. Just get all divs with class1 & 2 in the first instance.

Comment: We're reading the question differently. I'm reading it that he already has the thing (presumably as the result of some other operation) and now wants to test it for a combination of classes, *not* that he wants to go get it.

Comment: I'm in an each loop and need to check if $(this) selector have the classes that is stored in an array..

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
var $blah = $("blah");
if($blah.hasClass("test") && $blah.hasClass("othertest")){
 // something
}
```

... or use a selector

`$(".test.othertest");`

Comment: Ok, so maybe I have to exemplify:

  function checkFilter() {
  
   $('.post').each(function(){
    
     if ($(this).hasClass('photography') && $(this).hasClass('brindfors')) {
      $(this).show();
     } else {
      $(this).hide();
     }

   });
  }


But the problem in my case is that the classes (ex. photography & brindfors) I want to check for are in an array that is changing... So if I could have used hasClass(array) that would have been super. 

Any suggestion based on this example?

Comment: @emilolsson please edit your question with these info, it's not really readable in the comments ^^